Issue with redirecting a user after successfully logging into a Django app
I have a written a django app which requires a user to log in to access certain pages. The login process is working correctly but when they log in they are not been sent to the correct page and a 404 error is being displayed.
My URLS.py is
    path('contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='about'),
    path('login/',
         LoginView.as_view
         (
             template_name='app/login.html',
             authentication_form=forms.BootstrapAuthenticationForm,
             extra_context=
             {
                 'title': 'Log in',
                 'year' : datetime.now().year,
             }
         ),
         name='login'),

My settings.py is
"""
"
import os
import posixpath

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True
LOGIN_URL = '/api/login/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/api/listsystemhazardcontrols/'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application references
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/settings/#std:setting-INSTALLED_APPS
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'app',
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_simplejwt',
    'djoser', 
    # Add your apps here to enable them
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap5',
]

# Middleware framework

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'RiskManagementSoftware.urls'

# Template configuration

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
      #  'DIRS': [],
       #  'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app', 'templates')],  
       'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'app', 'templates', 'app')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
              
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'RiskManagementSoftware.wsgi.application'
# Database

DATABASES = {  
    'default': {  
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',  
        'NAME': 'cccc',  
        'USER': 'vvvv',  
        'PASSWORD': 'kvv,  
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',  
        'PORT': '3306',  
        'OPTIONS': {  
            'init_command': "SET sql_mode='STRICT_TRANS_TABLES'"  
        }  
    }  
}

# Password validation

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/i18n/
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATIC_ROOT = posixpath.join(*(BASE_DIR.split(os.path.sep) + ['static']))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')


DJOSER = {
    'SERIALIZERS': {
        'user': 'djoser.serializers.UserSerializer',
    },

    'EMAIL': {
        'activation': 'djoser.email.ActivationEmail',
        'password_reset': 'djoser.email.PasswordResetEmail',
    },
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL': 'password/reset/confirm/{uid}/{token}',
    'ACTIVATION_URL': 'activate/{uid}/{token}',
    'SEND_ACTIVATION_EMAIL': True,
    'SEND_CONFIRMATION_EMAIL': True,
    'PASSWORD_CHANGED_EMAIL_CONFIRMATION': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_RETYPE': True,
    'SET_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'LOGOUT_ON_PASSWORD_CHANGE': True,
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND': True,
    'USERNAME_RESET_SHOW_EMAIL_NOT_FOUND': True,
    'USER_CREATE_PASSWORD_RETYPE': True,
    'LOGIN_AFTER_REGISTRATION': False,
    'LOGIN_AFTER_ACTIVATION': False,
    'USER_DELETE': False,
}
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],}

I am using the built in django functionality for logging in and out from django.contrib.auth import login, authenticate
Could someone point me in the right direction?
I have tried various things for example pointing at different pages and writing custom views

Well where is this /api/listsystemhazardcontrols/' route defined in urls.py?

The LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL setting in your settings.py file have set to '/api/listsystemhazardcontrols/', but it appears that the URL pattern for /api/listsystemhazardcontrols/ does not exist in your urls.py file. Therefore, when a user logs in successfully, Django tries to redirect them to a non-existent page, resulting in a 404 error.
You need to ensure that the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL points to a valid URL pattern in your urls.py file. If you want to redirect users to the home page (/), you can simply set LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to '/', like the following:
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'

Alternatively, if you want to redirect users to a specific page after login, make sure that the corresponding URL pattern is defined in your urls.py file.
